# My implementation of Clojure's assoc-in

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, lisp

This is my implementation of Clojure's `assoc-in` function.  I am looking for tips on making it more idiomatic and in general, better.

```clj
(defn my-assoc-in
  [m [& ks] v]
  (let [sorted-keys (reverse ks)]
    (loop [curr-key (first sorted-keys)
           rem-keys (rest sorted-keys)
           curr-map (get-in m (reverse rem-keys))
           acc-val  (assoc curr-map curr-key v)]
      (if (empty? rem-keys)
        acc-val
        (let [next-key (first rem-keys)
              next-rem (rest rem-keys)
              next-map (get-in m next-rem)
              next-val (assoc next-map next-key acc-val)]
          (recur next-key next-rem next-map next-val))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
           curr-map (get-in m (reverse rem-keys))
```

That seems expensive (linear in number of keys).

At this point, isn't `(reverse rem-keys)` simply
`(rest ks)` ? That's available in O(1) rather than O(N) time.

---

```
           acc-val  (assoc curr-map curr-key v)]
      (if (empty? rem-keys)
        acc-val
        (let ...
```

We unconditionally create an `assoc` result.
But we only use it in the base case where there's no more keys.

Prefer to use that expression directly, eliding the `acc-val` symbol:

```
      (if (empty? rem-keys)
        (assoc curr-map curr-key v)
        (let ...
```

I get that you were shooting for parallel structure
with the four `let` variables.
The `next-val` down there is very nice
and should be retained since it reads smoothly.

BTW, even if you keep all eight identifiers,
there's an opportunity to rename to `curr-rem`
and `curr-val` if you want to call out the parallel structure.